# How to vary the start and end angles for my d3.js diagram?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to build a donut chart where I can vary the width of the "slices." I know I have to use the start and end angles, but I'm not sure how to reference the previous "slice" of the donut.

What I want is to be able to vary the width of the sections on the chart by the third value in each of the arrays in the data array.

```js
var data = [
  ['One', 32, .25],
  ['Two', 70, 1],
  ['Three', 55, 1.5],
  ['Four', 75, .75],
  ['Five', 29, .5],
  ['Six', 95, 1.5],
  ['Seven', 45, 2],
  ['Eight', 85, 1],
  ['Nine', 35, 1]
]

var r = 300
var p = Math.PI * 2

function update () {
  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(['#448', '#fdc', '#1b1'])
  var textColor = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(['#000', '#000', '#fff'])

  var svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 700 700")

  var group = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(350,350)')

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(r - 200)
      .outerRadius(function (d) { return (d.data[1] * 2) + 100 })
      //.startAngle(function(d, i) { return ( data[i] || 0 ) } )
      //.endAngle(function(d, i) { return data[i][2] + d.data[2] } )

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function (d) { return 1 })

  var arcs = group.selectAll('.arc')
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'arc')

  var paths = arcs.append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function (d) { return color(d.data)})

  var texts = arcs.append('text')
      .attr('transform', function (d) { return 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d) + ')' })
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('x', '50px')
      .attr('y', '-30px')
      .attr('fill', function (d) { return textColor(d.data)})
      .attr('font-family', 'Ubuntu')
      .attr('font-size', '22px')
      .html(function (d) {
        var line = d.data[0].split(' ')
        var tspans = line.map(function (word) {
          return `<tspan dx='-2.5em' dy='1.1em'>${word}</tspan>`
        }).join('')
        return tspans
      })
}
update()
```

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  color: #1b1b1b;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
svg g { transition: .75s; }
svg g.arc:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: How do you define the angle of each arc? By `d.data[2]` ?

Comment: Yeah, d.data[2] will be the "width" of each pie slice. Ideally, I can just put a 0 to 2 in there with 1 being average, so the number would act like a multiplier. I'm good on figuring out the math, what's tripping me up is accessing the endAngle of the previous pie slice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate start and and positions (in relative weights) with reduce:

```
const positions = data.reduce((arr, d) => {
 const from = arr.length > 0 ? arr[arr.length - 1].to : 0; 
 return [...arr, {from, to: from + d[2]}]; 
}, []);
```

Then, translate those positions to radians:

```
const sum = positions[positions.length - 1].to;
const toAngle = val => val / sum * 2 * Math.PI; 
const angles = positions.map(pos => 
  ({from: toAngle(pos.from), to: toAngle(pos.to)})
);
```

Now, you can set `startAngle` and `endAngle` for each arc:

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(r - 200)
  .outerRadius(function (d) { return (d.data[1] * 2) + 100 })
  .startAngle((d, i) => angles[i].from)
  .endAngle((d, i) => angles[i].to)
```

```js
var data = [
  ['One', 32, .25],
  ['Two', 70, 1],
  ['Three', 55, 1.5],
  ['Four', 75, .75],
  ['Five', 29, .5],
  ['Six', 95, 1.5],
  ['Seven', 45, 2],
  ['Eight', 85, 1],
  ['Nine', 35, 1]
];

const positions = data.reduce((arr, d) => {
 const from = arr.length > 0 ? arr[arr.length - 1].to : 0; 
 return [...arr, {from, to: from + d[2]}]; 
}, []);
const sum = positions[positions.length - 1].to;
const toAngle = val => val / sum * 2 * Math.PI; 
const angles = positions.map(pos => 
  ({from: toAngle(pos.from), to: toAngle(pos.to)})
);


var r = 300
var p = Math.PI * 2

function update () {
  var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(['#448', '#fdc', '#1b1'])
  var textColor = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .range(['#000', '#000', '#fff'])

  var svg = d3.select('svg')
      .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMin meet")
      .attr("viewBox", "0 0 700 700")

  var group = svg.append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(350,350)')

  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
      .innerRadius(r - 200)
      .outerRadius(function (d) { return (d.data[1] * 2) + 100 })
      .startAngle((d, i) => i < angles.length ? angles[i].from : 0)
      .endAngle((d, i) => i < angles.length ? angles[i].to : 0)

  var pie = d3.layout.pie()
      .value(function (d) { return 1 })

  var arcs = group.selectAll('.arc')
      .data(pie(data))
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'arc')

  var paths = arcs.append('path')
      .attr('d', arc)
      .attr('fill', function (d) { return color(d.data)})

  var texts = arcs.append('text')
      .attr('transform', function (d, i) { return 'translate(' + arc.centroid(d, i) + ')' })
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('x', '50px')
      .attr('y', '-30px')
      .attr('fill', function (d) { return textColor(d.data)})
      .attr('font-family', 'Ubuntu')
      .attr('font-size', '22px')
      .html(function (d) {
        var line = d.data[0].split(' ')
        var tspans = line.map(function (word) {
          return `<tspan dx='-2.5em' dy='1.1em'>${word}</tspan>`
        }).join('')
        return tspans
      })
}
update()
```

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95%;
  color: #1b1b1b;
}
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
svg {
  margin-top: 2em;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}
svg g { transition: .75s; }
svg g.arc:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

<svg id="svg"></svg>
```

Comment: Nice! : ) Had to run a quick diff to see you adjusted the centeroid for positioning the text. This rocks! Thanks so much : )

Comment: Glad to help : )